# Existing Sharepoint list to replicate

Tags: json, sharepoint, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am working for a company that has several sites. The two sites use different IT systems. I have a sharepoint list from company A that I need to replicate in company B. The list was done by someone else so I am not familiar with all the functionalities it might have.

I am a very new user of sharepoint when it comes to creating lists. I have a couple of questions:

1. On the existing list of company A, what checks would you perform to know all the customization the list has. (JSON or Calculated fields and so on) with a view of duplicating them in company B.
2. Is it possible to somehow download this list with all its customised columns from company A and upload it in company B? (I suspect no but thought to ask the experts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a new list based on existing list in **same** SharePoint tenant, you can create a list from existing list like:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Create a new list based on the columns in another list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-new-list-based-on-the-columns-in-another-list-49666e8c-8c48-414f-8e5e-dc0e232acd27)

---

If you are trying to create a new list based on existing list in **different** SharePoint tenant, try using PnP Provisioning engine and PnP PowerShell for exporting the list/site templates and use those in new SharePoint tenant.

Check these documentations:

1. [Introducing the PnP provisioning engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/introducing-the-pnp-provisioning-engine)
2. [Export-PnPListToSiteTemplate](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Export-PnPListToProvisioningTemplate.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you could try: save the list as a template (there is a menu item to do so in the list settings), download it, and then create a new list from that template in another place (same, menu item).

Comment: That I could try if i wanted to create the list within the same company. Here, I am trying to duplicate or recreate a list from company A to company B where IT systems aren't linked.

Comment: After you downloaded the list template from company A, then upload the list template  into company B (site settings -> list template gallery) to create replicated list.

Answer (score 0):

Due to company policy on the risks associated with allowing template creation (because a script has to be ran to allow this option). I ended up creating a list from scratch.
I went to my list, list settings then created each of the column ensuring the colluvion type is the same (especially for calculated fields). Then did a copy and paste of the formulas. When creating new columns, ensure the column names are the same so the calculated field work, unless you amend the formulas accordingly). Thanks to those who took the time to suggest ways to fix this.